# Is there a command to display apache vhost config?

Tags: apache, vhosts

I work on a development system that has hundreds of virtual hosts and vhost configs. Manually identifying which file path, hostname and vhost configs are related can be time consuming and may not always produce accurate or complete results.

Is there an Apache command that will display the vhost configurations related to a given hostname or path?

Comment: This command doesn't really answer my own question, but it does solve my problem:  `cat \`grep -ilR 'hostname or path here in quotes here' ./sites-available\``.  I still would like to know if there is an apache command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no such command, but you can use 'apache2ctl -S' (or 'httpd -S', depending on your distribution) to have a list of every Virtual Hosts and where they are defined.

Note that -s is a shorter synonym for '-t -D DUMP_VHOSTS'.

Comment: Yes, definitely a useful command, but it doesn't return the information in the vhost file, just the path of the vhost file.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your vhosts are neatly organised in files, and those files somewhat represent the hostname this might work on the command line

```
grep "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
```